# Need help finding G. Pick's 1917 article "Über affine Geometrie iv: Differentialinvarianten der Flächen gegenüber affinen Transformationen"

Tags: affine-geometry, online-resources, reference-works

I'm studying affine geometry and I need help finding this article
"**Über affine Geometrie iv: Differentialinvarianten der Flächen gegenüber affinen Transformationen**" written by G. Pick in 1917.

I've looked everywhere online and unfortunately I could not find the full article.

Comment: My german is nicht so gut, so I can't tell if there's a download link somewhere on this page (I couldn't find one), but have you looked around [this archive](https://archiv.saw-leipzig.de/36701ae19060401b9811dcc3a1bc1cce)?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor it seems to be that paper, however I didn't find any information for a pdf version of it, neither could find the library where it is.